# Extracting parts of string and place parts into a char array and another string variable C++

Tags: c++, string, arrays

I am writing a program that receives a string of characters
(example: abc1235 TFFTTFF TTFT)
This string must be split into two sections:
      student ID (abc1235)
      test answers (TFFTTFF TTFT)
studentID will be a string and testAnswers will be a char array (20 characters).

How would I extract the two data types and place them into their respective locations?

*the studentID is not a set length. A single space will separate the studentID and testAnswers. The testAnswers must be able to contain spaces representing any questions left blank.

*Compiler is Visual Studio Express C++

Comment: Whats the exact string look like you receive, maybe you can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is space-delimited, you can read the `studentID` into a `string` (ex: `cin >> studentID`). You can then write a [loop](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) to read 20 characters (`char` datatype) into your `testAnswers` array.